# How to prevent saving over an existing entity with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

(Samples in Kotlin)

I have an entity with manually assigned IDs:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
class Item {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ItemId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  var id: Int? = null

  @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
  var name: String? = null
}
```

and the Spring Data REST repository for it:

```
interface ItemRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Item, Int>
```

If I do a `POST` to `/items` using an existing ID, the existing object is overwritten. I would expect it to throw back an error. Is there a way to configure that behavior without rolling my own save method for each resource type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a [Spring Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation) for this with the help of [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators).

I created the validator like this:

```
class BeforeCreateItemValidator(private val itemRepository: ItemRepository) : Validator {
    override fun supports(clazz: Class<*>) = Item::class.java == clazz

    override fun validate(target: Any, errors: Errors) {
        if (target is Item) {
            itemRepository
                .findById(target.id!!)
                .ifPresent {
                    errors.rejectValue("id",
                                       "item.exists",
                                       arrayOf(target.id.toString()),
                                       "no default message")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And then set it up with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
class RestRepositoryConfiguration(
        private val beforeCreateItemValidator: BeforeCreateItemValidator
    ) : RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    override fun configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(
        validatingListener: ValidatingRepositoryEventListener) {
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", beforeCreateItemValidator)
    }
}
```

Doing this causes the server to return a `400 Bad Request` (I'd prefer the ability to change to a `409 Conflict`, but a `400` will do) along with a JSON body with an `errors` property containing my custom message. This is fine for my purposes of checking one entity, but if my whole application had manually assigned IDs it might get a little messy to have to do it this way. I'd like to see a Spring Data REST configuration option to just disable overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a version attribute to the entity annotated with `@Version` this will enable optimistic locking. If you provide always the version 0 with new entities you'll should get an exception when that entity does already exist (with a different version).

Of course you then need to provide that version for updates as well.

Comment: Found my own (different) solution before I got a chance to try this. Thanks!